# Имеется Swipe Views with Tabs состоит из 3 фрагментов.

Tags: android-viewpager, android, webview

Имеется Swipe Views with Tabs состоит из 3 фрагментов. 
В один из фрагментов не могу вставить WebView чтобы загрузить локальную страницу.
1 проблема Есть папка res/assets в ней есть mypage.html почему то пишет:
invalid resource directory name assets  /zTabsViewPager/res line 1  Android AAPT Problem
2 проблема The method findViewById(int) is undefined for the type Fragment1 Fragment1.java  /zTabsViewPager/src/com/scorebeyond/android/tabswithswipeexample    line 22 Java Problem

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {

    WebView myBrowser;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1,
            container, false);

        myBrowser = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
    myBrowser.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/mypage.html");

    return rootView;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Переместите директорию `assets` на уровень выше, в корень проекта.
2. `rootView.findViewById(…)`

Comment: Спасибо! Все по делу.